# Как составить правило в .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php, сервер

Всем привет!

Я не очень в htaccess разбираюсь. Хочу заменить второе на первое:

```
/image/min/10.jpg       /image.php&id=10&end=jpg&min=1
```

Пишу вот так:

```
RewriteRule ^/image/min/([0-9]{4}).(.*)+$ image.php?id=$1&end=$2&min=1 [L]
```

Но вот не работает что-то. В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: как минимум точку надо экранировать `\.` количество - `[0-9]{1,4}`

    /image/min/([0-9]{1,4})\.(.+)$

![Regular expression image](http://www.debuggex.com/i/rhR4NUBCmhcn3qqs.png)

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/rhR4NUBCmhcn3qqs)

Comment: вот последний вариант не работает ? `RewriteBase / ` есть ?

Comment: @eicto Неа. Вот работает такой вариант:

RewriteRule ^image/([^/]+).jpg$ image.php?id=$1&end=jpg [L]

Без экранизации точки, кстати. Но не устраивает явное указание "jpg", ибо может быть и другое расширение, а для каждого писать, как я понимаю, не логично.

P.S. Как вы в комментах код вставляете?

Comment: а так первый / уберите в моем выражении, у вас без экранирования точки работает только потому, что . это любой символ, попробуйте 

    /image/min/10ajpg


ps: 4 пробела слева

Comment: Во! Получилось, что так надо:

    RewriteRule ^image/min/([0-9]+).([^/]+)$ image.php?id=$1&end=$2&min=1 [L]

Comment: /image/min/10a.jpg покажет .jpg в $2

Comment: @eicto Слеш поставил и все ок. Спасибо большое! :)